# PhpStorm wrap/surround selection?

Tags: twig, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, settings

Often in coding and templating I need to wrap a certain part of text. Is there any shortcut to wrap the current selection, for example:

```
Hello World
"Hello World"

Hello World
{{ trans 'Hello World' }}
```

Im using PhpStorm 7 for Mac and PC. I found something similiar, with: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> you can wrap with a html-tag but nothing else. Also <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> comments the current selection according to the current file format(php, twig, html, ...)

Comment: **`Settings | Live Templates`** and use `$SELECTION$` -- should work for twig files as well. Once setup, use **Ctrl+Alt+J** to bring list of applicable templates. More details here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/high-speed-coding-with-custom-live-templates/

Answer (score 302):

I know this is a little late answer, but I hope anyone who looks this question get helped.
In PhpStorm, almost everything can be configured but a little tricky and takes some learning curve.

It's very common behaviour that select a word and type single quote (or double quote) to surround it.

```
Hello World
'Hello World'
"Hello World"
```

To enable this, tick on checkbox of **`Preferences -> IDE -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> Surround Selection on typing quote or brace`**.

Another way, you select something (word, condition) and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (on Mac) , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (on Windows). Available **`Surround With`** options dialog box will be displayed.

### Update (for PhpStorm8)

For **PhpStorm Version 8**, tick on checkbox of **`Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Surround selection on typing quote or brace`**.

### Update (for PhpStorm 2016)

For **PhpStorm Version 2016**, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (on Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (on Win) to go to **Settings**. Tick on checkbox of **Settings  -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Surround selection on typing quote or brace`**.

Comment: Update for phpstorm 8. File -> settings -> Editor -> Smartkeys -> Surround selection on typing quote or brace

Comment: Why isn't this the default consistent with other popular editors out there. Beats me.

Comment: Any version: Press CMD + Shift + A, search for Surround Selection, Press enter

Comment: I needed to use Ctrl + I to search through actions to find this instead of using search everywhere (configured to double tap shift)

Answer (score 26):

As of *2015-02-26* (**PhpStorm 8**) go to:

`File > Settings... > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Surround selection on typing quote or brace`

Answer (score 14):

How to create a live template to easily change `Hello World` into `{{ trans 'Hello World' }}`:

1. Select something (word, condition) and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (on Mac) , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (on Windows). Available Surround With options dialog box will be displayed.
2. Select **Configure live templates**.
3. On the right bar there are a "**+**" to add either a group or live template.
4. In Edit part choose "Abbreviation", so you could see it in a menu later.
5. In "Template text" add following: `{{ trans '$SELECTION$' }}`
6. Click *ok* to save changes.

After that select `Hello World` and use *step 1* from above, select a rule with your "Abbreviation"

This is just a more detailed answer than @Steve.NayLinAung .
Credit goes to @LazyOne

Comment: Good answer. You also can use CRTL ALT J to perform the wrap

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, it's

`PhpStorm > Preferences > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Surround selection on typing quote or brace`.

You can also press `command+,` to open the Preferences menu.