# Can I wrap a text selection in a tag in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose I have a text:

```
This is my text!

How beautiful it is!
```

And I want to wrap each line within a `p`-tag, is there an easier way than to navigate to each line and add them manually and have them close semi-automatically?

I want them to look like this:

```
<p>This is my text!</p>

<p>How beautiful it is!</p>
```

while having to do as less as possible.

Comment: Of course, right after posting I find the relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435802/phpstorm-wrap-surround-selection The Cmd + Alt + T (on Mac) , Ctrl + Alt + T solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this same question asked a day or two ago about WebStorm, but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

1. Select your lines
2. `Code | Surround With...`
   For Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
   For MacOS:  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
3. Choose **"Emmet"**
4. Type `p*` -- this will surround **each** line with `<p>` tag

[image: Screenshot of PhpStorm Emmet functionality]

NOTE: Empty lines will be wrapped as well so it is better remove them in advance.

[Similar/related case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20095020/783119).

---

**P.S.**

In current versions of IDE the dedicated **"Surround with Emmet"** action is available which allows you to bring that popup window in one key stroke instead of having going trough via intermediate `Surround with...` popup menu first.

That action has no shortcut defined by default, but you can easily change that and assign any desired shortcut in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- just look for `Other | Surround with Emmet` action (hint: use search box to speed up your search).

Comment: Is there a way that you know to make Emmet the default option?

Comment: @Timidfriendly What do you mean by "default option"?

Comment: The 'surround with' command currently brings up 3 options: 1. surround with tag. 2. surround with CDATA. 3. Emmet. I would like the first option to be Emmet.

Comment: @Timidfriendly That is not configurable. But you can press `e` to select that item in that list (instead of `Enter` for default one).

Comment: Btw is there a way to make it so you can create a shortcut which would wrap the text in tag of your choosing without actually typing the name of the tag?

Comment: @PetarVasilev Look at [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm#LiveTemplates%28Snippets%29inPhpStorm-CreatingSurroundTemplates) then ... or record a macro and assign custom shortcut to it.

Comment: Is it possible to do this and keep the carriage returns, so that it doesn't all appear on one line. Thanks

Comment: @raison Screenshots/examples please. Right now I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @LazyOne Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y13w0lsj9qn9580/Screenshot%202018-01-18%2021.12.06.png?dl=0

I would like it to process like this instead: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zn4wxptsnrlsib0/Screenshot%202018-01-18%2021.12.53.png?dl=0

Comment: @raison Show your Emmet settings. It works here. Right now it looks like you have `Single line` filter enabled.

Comment: Thanks for help @LazyOne -- PhpStorm Emmet Settings: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5i97ntv4yar2atb/Screenshot%202018-01-19%2012.50.34.png?dl=0

Comment: @raison Where did you try it? The context/file type. If it will be in empty HTML or PHP file -- yes, I see the same. But if it's inside the correct HTML (e.g. inside the `<div>` of a proper outer layout) -- it works fine. 1) https://postimg.org/image/5r6ocdtdh/ 2) https://postimg.org/image/hubzzsc3p/

Comment: Aha, that works. If I run it in an empty file then it is side by side. If I wrap it in a <div> then it keeps the returns. Thanks for that. https://www.dropbox.com/s/869fmcnuxgvehqj/Screenshot%202018-01-19%2013.09.40.png?dl=0

Comment: In Ubuntu 18 that key combination invokes the terminal.

Comment: @isherwood Check the Keymap used in IDE -- maybe you are using one that is not compatible with Ubuntu. If it meant to be compatible (correct keymap is used) -- change the shortcut for that action to something else that will not conflict with Ubuntu's special shortcut (`Settings | Keymap`).

Comment: **Use ctrl+alt+j instead**. This is an old answer so maybe it didn't exist before, but for this particular action `ctrl` + `alt` + `j` is superior, since "surround with" is the first option in the menu that appears. And, ctrl+alt+t is way too difficult than is reasonable to input if you have a large ergonomic keyboard.